# How to use Immutable library with Interface<T>

Tags: java, immutability, immutables-library

I want to make immutables my DTO object. For that, I want to use http://immutables.github.io/.

I have the next legacy hierarchy:

```
public interface Interface1 extends Serializable{
    public void method1();
}

public interface Interface2<T> extends Interface1{
    public void method2();
}

public class Implementation1<T> implements Interface2<T>{
    public void method1(){ }

    public void method2(){
        return null;
    }
}
```

For keeping backward compatibility, I want to imeplements a new interface and implementation as given below:

```
@Value.Immutable
public Interface3<T> extends Interface2<T>{
    public void method3();
}
```

That should generate ImmutableInterface3 class to be able to obtain a builder and to be able to build the class implementation.

The problem is that I can not use the next statement:

```
Interface3<Object> immutableImplementationOfInterface3 = ImmutableInterface3<Object>.builder().build();
```

Is there any problem with  in this solution?

Comment: Why can't you use that statement? Does the class not exist? Does the method not exist?

Comment: I just post the solution. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is:

```
Interface3<Object> immutableImplementationOfInterface3 = ImmutableInterface3.<Object> builder().build();
```